# How to create simple WCF service with VSCode editor?

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to create simple C# WCF service with VSCode editor on Windows?
I do not care about hosting at this point.

Comment: It might be possible, but it's hard. The classes required by WCF are not supported by .NET Core. For example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding?view=netframework-4.7&viewFallbackFrom=netcore-2.0 . It says "Not supported". So your goal will be to make VS Code/C# extension/Omnisharp support the full .Net Framework. But what is preventing you from using Visual Studio? The Community edition is free.

Comment: @vyrp I just have an old notebook that will not be able to run full VS smoothly.